# Can string cheese be frozen?

Tags: food-safety

Is it okay to freeze individually packaged string cheese?

I'm less concerned about what it does to the taste of the cheese, and more concerned about the safety of freezing the cheese with the plastic. I heard that there are certain plastics that should not be frozen, which is why I'm concerned.

If I had the name of the plastic being used, I'd probably be able to search for its safety online. However, the [manufacturer](http://www.preciouscheese.com/cheese/snack.php) does not list the type of plastic being used.

I've tried several searches online, but nothing yielded anything useful.

Comment: Never heard of a plastic that can't be frozen (other than obvious things, like a bottle full of water may burst, because water expands). The string cheese is probably in PE, or possibly PP. If you're lucky, there might be a resin code (recycle symbol) on it.

Answer (score 3):

Likely [Polyethylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene) / [Polyethylene terephthalate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_terephthalate#Safety)

[Despite internet rumors](http://www.plasticsinfo.org/beveragebottles/apc_faqs.html#8), freezing should be safe.

Your string cheese will likely be far more 'brittle and crumbly' than 'stringy' after thawing.

Comment: You should probably note that plasticsinfo.org run by the [American Chemistry Council](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Chemistry_Council), an industry trade association, so isn't an unbiased source.

Answer (score 2):

I froze once string cheese.

Despite the plastic bag freezing, the cheese tasted as it was, with no changes in its taste.